# cpp find the functions of the same class but not the vars

Tags: c++, class

the c++ file includes the header of his class and can find the public functions of the class but when I'm trying to access the private variables I get an error ""Course" has no member "_name"". I tried to public them but with no success, I compared them to working files but they're mostly the same.

header:

```
#ifndef COURSE_H
#define COURSE_H

#include <string>

class Course
{
public:
    void init(std::string name, unsigned int test1, unsigned int test2, unsigned int exam);
    unsigned int* getGradesList();
    std::string getName();
    double getFinalGrade();


private:
    std::string* _name;
    unsigned int _test1;
    unsigned int _test2;
    unsigned int _exam;
};

#endif // COURSE_H
```

c++:

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Course.h"

void Course::init(std::string name, unsigned int test1, unsigned int test2, unsigned int exam)
{
    this->_name = new std::string;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `init` really should be a constructor.

Comment: You probably don't want to allocate a `std::string` on the heap...

Comment: [Also, cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91dfc8051f9daf0f).

Comment: Why do you have `#pragma once` in a .cpp file?

Comment: You should only use precompiled headers for large projects.  There may not be any significant build time savings for small projects (the hassle of getting the order correct may not be worth using them).

Comment: BTW, you only need to use `this->` syntax when the member name is the same as the parameter name.  Not using it reduces defects (typos).

Comment: If you need to store more than one string, consider using `std::vector<std::string>` rather than dynamic memory allocation.